# Create a deterministic hash of fixed length from unordered arbitrary strings

Tags: encryption, hash, sha

I am trying to come up with a checksum algorithm that produces a hash of fixed length based on arbitrary strings that are un-ordered.

By that I mean to say, the hash of the strings `["a", "b"]` should result in the same hash as `["b", "a"]`. Also, `["this is a really long string", "a"]` should result in the same as [`"a", "this is a really long string"]`.

Ideally, I would like this hash to look something similar to a sha256 string, but that is less important.

The hash doesn't need to be unique, but it does need to act as a checksum, so for lots of inputs, it should be at least a bit unlikely that you'd get collisions.

As I say, this is a checksum rather than a cryptographic hash, so some degree of duplication is ok.

The pseudocode, written in go for no other reason than it's syntactically light whilst being typed, would be:

```
func hash(inputs []string) string
```

One option would be to simply order the inputs and create a sha256 from it, but that is memory intensive. Another option is to convert to uuid using a v5 uuid, and XOR it, but ideally the algorithm would require no other hashing function.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you need `["a", "b"]` to hash differently than `["ab", ""]`? If not, isn't this just "sort array, join into a string, hash?" To have them be different, that's just "sort array, join into a string separated by length of previous string, hash."

Comment: You might be looking at [locality sensitive hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing)

Answer (score 3):

Chose a hash algorithm that suits you need, and apply it on each element .. and then xor all the hash's together. This will give you the same result, independent of the sequence of the elements.

Comment: Be careful here. If the list may contain multiple instances of the same string, then it is easy to get collisions. {a, b, a} will hash to the same as {b,b,b} and {c,b,c}

Comment: @clausc That's correct .. adding the hashes instead might solve this.

Comment: To avoid this problem, in our implementation we accumulate XOR, mod sums, and mod products of each individual hash (any commutative function will do, of course), then hash the three accumulators to obtain the final hash.